# How to STOP a program in DartPad?

Tags: dart, asynchronous, playgrounds, dartpad

Using [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?), how do you stop the current program without losing all your code?

As it is, it seems there is only:

- a RUN button
- a RESET button (which wipes your code)

The answer is not:

- "just leave it running and click RUN again,"

(because evidently it doesn't stop the current code first, and in fact begins subsequent runs in parallel! ***)

- "just reload the browser tab"

(because what if you're needing to read rapidly changing console output? -- that would be gone)

*** You can verify this behavior with this code:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  
  int iter = 0;
  
  Timer myTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 10), (timer) {
    iter++;
   
    int temp = iter %1000;
    
    print("iter = $iter");
    print("iter %1000 = $temp");
  });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since DartPad can run Flutter apps, you can make your own Stop button.

[image]

[Run code sample in DartPad.](http://dartpad.dev/c7c8d111cb1d76e5506bbd4c32015883)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
  runDart();
}

Timer? myTimer;

void runDart() {
  int iter = 0;
  myTimer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), (timer) {
    iter++;
    int temp = iter %1000;
    print("iter = $iter");
    print("iter %1000 = $temp");
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Stop'),
          onPressed: () {
            myTimer?.cancel();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a command like exit() or finish() that would actually end the execution entirely?

Comment: @NerdyBunz I'm not sure.

Comment: @NerdyBunz Yes there is an [`exit()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-io/exit.html) command, but it requires importing the `dart:io` package which is not supported in the dartpad. Yet. If you'd like to know more, then check the description for the [`exit()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-io/exit.html)

Answer (score 3):

There is not a way to stop a program in DartPad **yet**. Here are some related issues on GitHub:

https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/668

https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/704